# Запрос select count(*) работает медленно

Tags: php, mysql

Подскажите, как возможно реализовать постраничную навигацию без использования select count , т.к он довольно много времени забирает ?

```
select count(*) from advert advert 
where advert.hide='show' and advert.moder='view' and on_delete='off' 
and blocked!='yes' and end_putdate>1603830570 
and n_category in (62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,85,86,87,149,151) 
and advert.country_adv = 3159 and advert.region_adv = 33 
and advert.city_adv = 5097
```

Нашел один комментарий, но не могу понять принцип его действия.
Буду признателен, если подскажите на примере .

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Этот метод не позволит вам показать сколько всего есть записей, эдакий урезанный пагинатор)

Comment: много забирает это сколько? и сколько у вас всего данных в таблице? и каков запрос на выборку и подсчет, мб в них проблема?

Comment: @teran от 0.5 до 1.3 сек (скрин) . 400к записей

Comment: select count(*) 
   from advert advert
   where  advert.hide='show' and advert.moder='view' and on_delete='off' and blocked!='yes' and end_putdate>1603830570   and n_category in (62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,85,86,87,149,151)  and advert.country_adv =  3159  and advert.region_adv =  33  and advert.city_adv =  5097 ;

Answer (score -1):

На скриншоте представлено бессмысленное решение бессмысленной задачи.
Если запрос с count работает медленно, то запрос без count **тоже** работает медленно.
Поэтому надо заниматься оптимизацией запросов, а не плясками с бубном.

То есть правильный ответ: если запрос с count работает медленно, то надо оптимизировать свои запросы.

Comment: можете уточнить, на что нужно обратить внимание в первую очередь при оптимизации этого запроса?
Просто select очень быстро работает, а вот count медленней

Comment: В таблице есть вообще *хоть один* индекс?

Comment: конечно, без индексов было очень туго .. Прикрепил скрин

Comment: тогда не может быть чтобы count(*) работала медленно. показывай EXPLAIN SELECT count(*) ... и весь запрос целиком, а не огрызок.

Comment: прикрепил в топе

Comment: а в **вопрос** добавить нельзя было? и оформить при этом нормально?

Comment: я добавлял в вопрос

Comment: ну вот explain тебе пишет что ему надо перебрать 88 тысяч строк. по идее, чтобы работало быстро, надо добавить в индекс все поля, участвующие в запросе